# Send form data as array of objects to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where i dynamically render checkbox items with razor. User can make adjustments and then i need to send form back to controller. If i send only one item i.e. row, it works fine, but if i try to send all of them i always get null. How can i collect form data properly. This is what i have at the moment.

```
public void SendData(List<SomeClass> myData)
    {
        var data = myData; //always null
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public bool R { get; set; }
        public bool W { get; set; }
        public bool E { get; set; }
        public bool D { get; set; }
    }
```

And view:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var test = $("#myForm").serialize();

        console.log(test);

        test = JSON.stringify({ 'myData': test });

        console.log(test);

        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/SendData',
            data: test,
            success: function () {

            },
            failure: function (response) {

            }
        });
    });

    </script>


        <form id="myForm">

        <div class="row control_group">
            @Html.Hidden("Id", 1)
            @Html.Hidden("RoleId", 1)
            @Html.CheckBox("R", false)
            @Html.CheckBox("W", false)
            @Html.CheckBox("E", false)
            @Html.CheckBox("D", false)
        </div>

        <div class="row control_group">
            @Html.Hidden("Id", 2)
            @Html.Hidden("RoleId", 2)
            @Html.CheckBox("R", true)
            @Html.CheckBox("W", true)
            @Html.CheckBox("E", true)
            @Html.CheckBox("D", true)
        </div>

    </form>
```

EDIT:

This is how i render items with razor

```
    foreach (SomeObject x in items)
    {
        var menuName = someStringFromDb;
        var permissions = x.MainItem.FirstOrDefault();

            <div class="row control_group">
                <div class="col-sm-4">@menuName</div>
                <input name="Id" type="hidden" value="@permissions.Id"/>
                <input name="RoleId" type="hidden" value=@permissions.RoleId />
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.CheckBox("R", @permissions.Read)
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.CheckBox("W", @permissions.Write)
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.CheckBox("E", @permissions.Edit)
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.CheckBox("D", @permissions.Delete)
                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Thank you for your answer @Avi Fatal it got me this far. Problem i am facing now is this. Checkbox elements rendered by razor have two inputs, one is hidden and other one is shown. When i collect form data i am always getting last input value (hidden one, that's always false) How can i get true value?

[image]

Current data sent to controller (everything is false):

```
{"ajaxData":[{"Id":"1","RoleId":"1","R":"false","W":"false","E":"false","D":"false"},{"Id":"2","RoleId":"2","R":"false","W":"false","E":"false","D":"false"}]}
```

Collecting data like this (found similar problem here on SO):

```
var ajaxData = $('.control_group').map(function (i, group) {
                var data = {};
                $(group).find(':input').each(function () {
                    data[this.name] = this.value;
                });
                return data;
            }).get();

            ajaxData = JSON.stringify({ 'ajaxData': ajaxData });

            console.log(ajaxData);
```

**EDIT 3**

With only .serialize() i get null as input parameter on controller, with JSON.stringify i get Count = 0, also empty. What am i missing?

HTML:

```
        @model List<WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController.SomeClass>

    <form id="myForm">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>Element</div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].RoleId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].R)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].W)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].E)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].D)
        }
    </form>

    <button id="send">SEND</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#send').on('click', function () {

            var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
            console.log(data);

            //data = JSON.stringify({ 'ajaxData': data });

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/SendData',
                data: data,
                success: function () {

                },
                failure: function (response) {

                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Controller

```
public void SendData(IEnumerable<SomeClass> ajaxData)
    {
        var data = ajaxData;
    }
```

Comment: You have not shown how you are dynamically generating the form controls, but the html you have shown has `name` attributes without indexers so will not bind to a collection. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: Unfortunately adding indexes to names didn't work (following first and second link from your comment)

Comment: Of course it works. If its not working for you, then consider posting the code you have used so we can correct your errors

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls in a view. You need to use `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) @Html.CheckBoxFor(m -> m[i].R) .... }` so that your controls are correctly named.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have done it just like that, but when i try to serialize it i get single object with all input elements (that's two for each checkbox). I am serializing it like var data = $("#myForm").serialize();

Comment: Yes, and when you post back to the method which has a parameter for your model (i.e. `List<SomeClass> model`), the `DefaultModelBinder` will correctly set the value of all the `boolean` properties!

Comment: Please check Edit 3. On controller side i get null when i send data from view. Is the serialization problem or am i sending it the wrong way?

Comment: I was sending it the wrong way since i was trying to do it with JSON before this i accidentally left contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', in ajax call. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me some time to understand the problem (-:

Anyway, I have created a small test, and it is working.

```
public class User
{
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public void TestPost(List<User> users)
{

}
```

you need to serialize your data to json array of objects, 
`[{ 'UserName': "user 1" }, { 'UserName': "user 2" }]` a little jquery manipulation... (see here: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery))

```
$.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/TestPost',
            data: JSON.stringify([{ 'UserName': "user 1" }, { 'UserName': "user 2" }]),
            dataType: "json",
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Avi Fatal it got me this far (see edit 2). Problem i am facing now is this. Checkbox elements rendered by razor have two inputs, one is hidden and other one is shown. When i collect form data i am always getting last input value (hidden one, that's always false) How can i get true value?

Comment: Hi, please accept the anwer and open another thread, it is a different problem. it does not belong here... ill look in to it when you open a new thread.

Comment: I have, it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896965/get-correct-checkbox-value-when-using-razor-asp-net-mvc